# Why is my file array not in numeric order?

Tags: c#, .net, arrays, file, sorting

```
var files = Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\Users\user\Downloads\CaptchaCollection\Small").OrderBy(name => name).ToArray();

for (int i = 0; i < files.Length; i++)
{
    MessageBox.Show(files[i].ToString());
}
```

So I was testing my files array with the message box but it seems like it's not giving the name in order.

My file names are *n*.png, where *n* is a number. There is no pattern since I deleted some images.

So here is the output so far:

```
1
1001
1006
1008
1009
101
1016
1017
1019
1026
....
```

Normally in ascending order manually I'd get something like:

```
1
2
4
5
7
...
```

How do I sort this array so that everything is in numeric order??

Comment: possible duplicate of [Natural Sort Order in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/248603/natural-sort-order-in-c-sharp)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The list is ordered in alphabetical order. What you want is to order them as numbers. You can do that if they **are** numbers:

```
Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\Users\user\Downloads\CaptchaCollection\Small").
    Select(name => int.Parse(Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(name))).
    OrderBy(number => number).
    ToArray();
```

If you would want to filter out filenames that would not be a number while still using linq you could do this:

```
Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\Users\user\Downloads\CaptchaCollection\Small").
    Select(nameWithExtension => Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(nameWithExtension)).
    Where(name => {int number; return int.TryParse(name, out number);}).
    Select(name => int.Parse(name)).
    OrderBy(number => number).
    ToArray();
```

Comment: Thanks so much :) @Steve Thanks for pointing this out too in case I accidentally put some non-numerics there.